# Bigcommerce API connection error

Tags: php, api, connection, e-commerce

I am new to the Big-commerce.

I am try to connect the PHP API of the Big-commerce  below is my code.

```
BigCommerce_Api::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'mystore url',
    'username'  => 'admin',
    'api_key'   => 'my apikey'
));

$ping = BigCommerce_Api::getTime();
if ($ping) 
{
    echo $ping->format('H:i:s');
}
else
{
    echo "error in connection";
}
```

i am try to display the time if connection is completed but getting error.

is there any problem in my code?

Please help me out form this problem.

Comment: Do they provide support and/or documentation?

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? What does var dump of $ping show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default generated URL looks like `https://uniquestoreid.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/`, when using BigCommerce API remove `api/v2` from URL, your config should look like this:

```
BigCommerce_Api::configure(
    array(
        'store_url' => 'https://uniquestoreid.mybigcommerce.com',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'api_key'   => 'longtokenstring'
    )
);
```